# How to link css files more than two directories up

Tags: html, css, vs-web-site-project

I am creating a big websites and I have subfolders inside subfolder inside sub folder

- Media mania

  - html

    - **index.html**
    - Nature

      - Animals

        - Birds

          - **Penguin.html**
  - css

    - Nature

      - Animals

        - Birds

          - **Penguin.css**

How would you connect penguin.css to penguin.html. I do know how to link a CSS file to an HTML file but I've only done them 2 directories up and I do know you go up a dir with **./** so I have tried `...../` and `..../` but they both didnt work.

Comment: Have you tried the format ../../../?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of `penguin.html`, you put

```
<link href="../../../../../css/Nature/Animals/Birds/Penguin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Each ../ brings you to the folder above, so you need to go up 5 times - then you are in Media Mania, and can move back down with css/Nature etc.

Comment: @mahatmasammatman Thanks.....I just though you added a dots then added a backslash at then end for no apparent reason at all, not ../ each time